# DataProperty from ontology using keywords from rake and owlready2

Tags: python, rake, ontology, owlready

I am trying to extract the value of a dataProperty:
if I test this ----> it works !

```
keywords="Tunisia"
key="*"+keywords+"*"
country= onto.search(iri=key)
country
print(country[1].recovered, country[1].cases) ------> ['216'] ['949']
```

But when I try this :

```
        r.extract_keywords_from_text("Tunisia")
        words=r.get_ranked_phrases()
        keywords=str(words)
        key="*"+keywords+"*"
        country= onto.search(iri=key)
        if len(country)>0:

            print(country[1].recovered,country[1].cases)

        else:
            print("no cases")
```

**this error appears :** 
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 8, in 
    print(country[1].recovered,country[1].cases)

File "C:\Users\stef info\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\owlready2\prop.py", line 243, in **getattr**
    raise AttributeError("Property can only have annotation property values!")

AttributeError: Property can only have annotation property values!

how can I fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by replacing

```
       keywords=str(words)
       key="*"+keywords+"*"
```

by

```
        key="*"+words[0]+"*"
```